# Problem in Keras with 'merge' - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: tensorflow, merge, keras, tensor, array-merge

I tried to merge **layer3**, **layer4** and **layer5** with following line of code:

```
layer = merge([layer3,layer4,layer5],mode='sum')
```

But it throws this error:

> show the TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Why is my code not working?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: he's trying to use deprecated keras methods of summation, regarding layers

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're trying to run source code written for an older Keras version. 'sum' just adds your layers element wise. You could also use TensorFlow to do the same:

```
layer = tf.add(layer3, layer4)
layer = tf.add(layer, layer5)
```